# Rename Columns in Python using Regular Expressions

Tags: python

I have a data set that has columns for number of units sold in a given month - the problem being that the monthly units columns are named in MM/yyyy format, meaning that I have 12 columns of units information per record.

So for instance, my data looks like:

```
ProductID  |  CustomerID  |  04/2018  |  03/2018  |  02/2018  |  FileDate  |
a1032      |  c1576       |     36    |     12    |     19    | 04/20/2018 |
```

What causes this to be problematic is that a new file comes in every month, with the same file name, but different column headers for the units information based on the last 12 months.

What I would like to do, is rename the monthly units columns to Month1, Month2, Month3... based on a simple regex such as `([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)` that will result in the output:

```
ProductID  |  CustomerID  |   Month1  |   Month2  |   Month3  |  FileDate  |
a1032      |  c1576       |     36    |     12    |     19    | 04/20/2018 |
```

I know that this should be possible using Python, but as I have never used Python before (I am an old .Net developer) I honestly have no idea how to achieve this.

I have done a bit of research on renaming columns in Python, but none of them mentioned pattern matching to rename a column, eg:

```
 df = df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'})
```

UPDATE: The data that I am showing in my example is only a subset of the columns; total, in my data set I have 120 columns, only 12 of which need to be renamed, this is why I thought that regex might be the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

# regex pattern
pattern = re.compile("([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)")

# get headers as list
headers = list(df)

# apply regex
months = 1
for index, header in enumerate(headers):
    if pattern.match(header):
        headers[index] = 'Month{}'.format(months)
        months += 1

# set new list as column headers
df.columns = headers
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have some set names that you want to convert to, then rather than using rename, it might easier to just pass a new list to the df.columns attribute

```
df.columns = ['ProductID','CustomerID']+['Month{}'.format(i) for i in range(12)]+['FileDate']
```

If you want to use rename, if you can write a function `find_new_name` that does the conversion you want for a single name, you can rename an entire list `old_names` with

```
df.rename(columns = {oldname:find_new_name(old_name) for old_name in old_names})
```

Or if you have a function that takes a new name and figures out what old name corresponds to it, then it would be

```
df.rename(columns = {find_old_name(new_name):new_name for new_name in new_names})
```

You can also do

```
for new_name in new_names:
    old_name = find_new_name(old_name)
    df[new_name] = df[old_name]
```

This will copy the data into new columns with the new names rather than renaming, so you can then subset to just the columns you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - one of the reasons that I was considering Regex is because my full data set contains 120 columns. I realized I did not include this information in my question and have updated it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Since [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) could take a function as a mapper, we could define a customized function which returns a new column name in the new format if the old column name matches regex; otherwise, returns the same column name. For example,

```
import re


def mapper(old_name):
    match = re.match(r'([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)', old_name)
    if match:
        return 'Month{}'.format(int(match.group(1)))
    return old_name

df = df.rename(columns=mapper)
```